# Losing layout properties, (probably) because of using replaceWith() method

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make an interactive content. In this I plan to use the replaceWith() method. Everything is made with jQueryMobile, so it already has a default layout. The problem is that it seems that those layout properties are not being called when I used the replaceWith() method.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

The code:

```
   function viewNews(){
    $('#newsPage').replaceWith('<div data-role="content" id="newsPage"><ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="articleList"><li></li></ul></div>');

    for(var i = 2; i<=maxLength; i++) {
        $('#articleList li:last').after('<li id="list' + i + '"><a style="font-size: x-small" href="#article' + i + '">'+ storedTitles[i] +'</a></li>');
enter code here}
}



//======= NEWS OVERVIEW PAGE ========
document.write(
  ' <div data-role="page" id="news">' +
  '     <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">' +
  "         <h1>What's on Xiamen</h1>" +
  '         <a data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext" onClick="refresh()">Refresh</a>' +
  '     </div>' +
  '     <div data-role="content" id="newsPage">' +
  '         <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="articleList">'
);
for(var i=1; i<=maxLength; i++){
 document.write(
  '             <li id="list' + i + '"><a style="font-size: x-small" href="#article' + i + '">'+ storedTitles[i] +'</a></li>'
  );
}
document.write(
  '         </ul>' +
  '     </div>' +
  '     <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">' +
  '     <div data-role="navbar">' +
  '      <ul>' +
  '         <li><a href="#news" data-back="true" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">News</a></li>' +
  '         <li><a href="#profile" >Profile</a></li>' +
  '         <li><a href="#friends" >Friends</a></li>' +
  '         <li><a href="#settings" >Settings</a></li>' +
  '      </ul>' +
  '     </div>' +
  '     </div>' + 
  ' </div>'
);
```

The bottom part is done first, actually. The viewNews() function is being called in another function, refresh(), which is triggered by pressing on a button. It functions perfect, exactly what I want, but it doesn't look like what I want... So in functionality, no problems.

Hope you see what's the problem! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just replace the html inside the `div` tag (otherwise it seems circular):

```
$('#newsPage').html('<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="articleList"><li></li></ul>').trigger( 'updatelayout' );
```

**EDIT:** Try adding `trigger('updatelayout')`.  From your issue, it appears that Jquery Mobile isn't listening for `data-xxxx` attributes within revisions.

If `trigger('updatelayout')` works great, if not you could test my hunch by individually updating the content of the `<li>` elements to see if they stay the way they initialized.

Comment: You have several odd `data-xxxx` attributes.  Are you relying on them for CSS with some other code?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using jQuery js and css and jQueryMobile js

Comment: Where would I add this trigger? I have never heard of that before... Sounds promising :P

Comment: Did you test my hunch?  Make a jsfiddle, so we can see the problem.